# Gett %3f at the end of my url

Tags: .htaccess

I keep getting %3F at the end of my url can you jelp

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Merchant2/Merchant.mvc$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=MTS&Category_Code=Precision_Measuring_Tools (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mansontool.com/merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=MTS&Category_Code=PrecMeasTools [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule with `NE` flag (No Escape):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=MTS&Category_Code=Precision_Measuring_Tools
RewriteRule ^Merchant2/Merchant\.mvc$ http://www.mansontool.com/merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=MTS&Category_Code=PrecMeasTools [R=301,L,NE]
```